# What is wrong with appName function?

Tags: python, py4j

When I run the spark's main function in jupyter python I get an error at `.appName` function

```
spark=ps.sql.SparkSession.builder\
    .master('local[4]')\
     .appName('spark-lecture')\
    .getOrCreate()
sc= spark.sparkContext
```

> Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't import the right things.
Did you try the following (taken from the docs):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('local[4]') \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL basic example") \
    .getOrCreate()
```